# tsql inner merge join

Tags: t-sql, merge, inner-join

we've got some simple sql-queries, joining several tables with inner joins.
indices are existing, and no missing indices are suggested by optimizer.

the queries run fine on our test-environment and several other systems.
we've applied the sql to another system, and the query breaks down.
runtime on own server: nearly instant.
runtime on new server: about 40 seconds.

the amount of data is matchable.

adding the "merge" hint to the inner join gives the estimated runtimes, known from the own server.

why those differences?

we're on ms-sql 2008 r2.

Comment: On the server which doesn't give you the merge join what type of join does it give you? Is there a big discrepancy between actual and estimated numbers of rows? (You can see this in the actual execution plan) Check that auto create statistics and auto update statistics are turned on.

Comment: Are the statistics on the new server up to date?  They may not be, right after a restore

Answer (score 1):

Maybe parallel execution settings and evironment are different on the "slow" system.

Hinting the "merge join" probably you replaced a loop join.

The best way to be sure is to get the query plans generated in the two different systems, and look at differences.